# Keys are not being serialized for CoreNLPServer TimeAnnotator

Tags: java, stanford-nlp

As described [here](https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP/issues/483), I made a custom annotator for CoreNLP TimeAnnotator using the following properties file

```
customAnnotatorClass.time = edu.stanford.nlp.time.TimeAnnotator

annotators = tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma, ner, time

ner.useSUTime = true
```

But I received an error when trying to use the `time` annotator on the server `Keys are not being serialized: class edu.stanford.nlp.time.TimeAnnotations$TimexAnnotations` , here's the full error

```
edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.ProtobufAnnotationSerializer$LossySerializationException: Keys are not being serialized: class edu.stanford.nlp.time.TimeAnnotations$TimexAnnotations
at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.ProtobufAnnotationSerializer.toProto(ProtobufAnnotationSerializer.java:424)
at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.ProtobufAnnotationSerializer.toProtoBuilder(ProtobufAnnotationSerializer.java:636)
at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.ProtobufAnnotationSerializer.toProto(ProtobufAnnotationSerializer.java:592)
at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.ProtobufAnnotationSerializer.write(ProtobufAnnotationSerializer.java:184)
at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.outputAnnotation(StanfordCoreNLP.java:1016)
at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.lambda$createOutputter$35(StanfordCoreNLP.java:980)
at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLPServer$CoreNLPHandler.handle(StanfordCoreNLPServer.java:876)
at jdk.httpserver/com.sun.net.httpserver.Filter$Chain.doFilter(Filter.java:77)
at jdk.httpserver/sun.net.httpserver.AuthFilter.doFilter(AuthFilter.java:82)
at jdk.httpserver/com.sun.net.httpserver.Filter$Chain.doFilter(Filter.java:80)
at jdk.httpserver/sun.net.httpserver.ServerImpl$Exchange$LinkHandler.handle(ServerImpl.java:692)
at jdk.httpserver/com.sun.net.httpserver.Filter$Chain.doFilter(Filter.java:77)
at jdk.httpserver/sun.net.httpserver.ServerImpl$Exchange.run(ServerImpl.java:664)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830)
```

Comment: Most probably, the fields of your class are not serializable.

Comment: @minhazur It's not actually my class, it's the Timex annotation object in stanford CoreNLP!

Comment: sorry, I don't have much idea on that. Check, whether this helps https://www.javatips.net/api/edu.stanford.nlp.time.timeannotations.timexannotations